# How Vulnerability scanners assign CVE codes to Vulnerability found

Tags: cve, siem, vulnerability-management

I just want to know how CVE codes are assigned by the vulnerability scanners, while it found the particular vulnerability.

Answer (score 6):

Usually it'll be the other way around, a scanner will have a list of known CVEs and how to test for them. It will then give you a filtered version of that list based on which vunerabilities apply to the system under test.

Answer (score 0):

CVE codes are maintained and assigned by the MITRE Corporation.

[Wikipedia - CVE Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Vulnerabilities_and_Exposures)

Comment: If you look at the [CVE identifiers section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Vulnerabilities_and_Exposures#CVE_identifiers), CVE codes are assigned by CVE numbering authorities. While MITRE is the _primary_ numbering authority, there are others.

Comment: Which means this answer basically repeats the first answer